# How to update the length of a vector in matlab if statement

Tags: matlab, for-loop

I'm using MATLAB to write a function, which can find all elements in vector v that are equal to scalar `a`, and change each one of them to `[b c]`, finally return the new vector w. If `v = [1 2 5], a = 2, b = 4, c = 3,` then the result is `w = [1 4 3 5]`.

Below is my code

```
function w = change(v, a , b ,c )


for ii = 1:length(v)
    if v(ii) == a
       v_1 = v(1:ii-1);
       v_2 = v(ii+1:length(v));
       v_3 = [b c];
       v = [v_1 v_3 v_2];
    end 
end 


w = v;

end
```

However, the problem is: `for` statement will only read the length of the `v` before the first run of the loop, in this way, if the size of vector is increased, then `length(v)` in if statement will not be updated thus `ii` can not cover all the element indices. For example, if my input is `([1 2 2 2 3 2 4 5 6 2], 2, 4, 4)`, then with my code, `for` will stop at `ii = 10`, which is length of the old `v`, and give a wrong result `[1 4 4 4 4 4 4 3 4 4 4 5 6 2]`, which does not change the last element (because ii doesn't cover 15).

My question is: how to update `length(v)` in `if` statement? or is there any other better way to finish this task?

Thank you very much.

Comment: You can convert your numeric array to a cell array and use `cellfun` to change the elements. I believe the code will be cleaner that way.

Comment: Bonus points for not using `i` as a loop variable:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simpler method than checking each element in a loop is to find where the new elements will go, by using `find(v==a)` and just loop on those cases (taking care with the indexing!):

```
s = find(v==a);
v(end+1:end+numel(s))=0;
for ii=1:numel(s)
    ind=s(ii)+ii;
    v(ind-1:end)=[b c v(ind:end-1)];
end
```

Comment: IT'S AMAZING! It took me 10 mins to understand your code! Especially why subtract `1` in `v(ind-1:end)=[b c v(ind:end-1)];` (because you want to drop one `0` at the tail of the vector). It's really a neat method!

Answer (score 2):

I think this will be easier if you do it with cell arrays.

```
function w = change(v, a , b ,c )
    cellV = num2cell(v);
    cellW = cellfun(@(x)(subFunction(x,a,b,c)),cellV,'uni',0);
    w = [cellW{:}];
end

function out = subFunction(val,a,b,c)
    if (val == a)
        out = [b c];
    else
        out = x;
    end
end
```

Comment: Thanks buddy! I was confused about how to use `cellfun` and I tried to use `for` loop to change every element in the cell. Your code is a great lesson for me :)